# My dataframe is not updating when using loc

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, flask

I am making a small website for class and I cant seem to change data in a dataframe and get it into my csv.

I think it has something to do with it being a copy or view. I do keep getting the warning ("A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame error with flask")  Below is the code and this is my first time posting so be gentle!

```
def change_password(username, new_password):
    """Changes user password"""
    user_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sys.path[0] + "\\" + "passfile.csv"))
    user_data.set_index('usernames',inplace=True)

    if not check_username(username):


        print('TEST1', file=sys.stderr)
        user_data.loc[username]['passwords'] = 4
        print(user_data)
        print('TEST2', file=sys.stderr)
            
        user_data.reset_index()
        user_data.to_csv(os.path.join(sys.path[0] + "\\" + "passfile.csv"))
        flash('Changed Password!')
```

***UPDATE***
Here is more context to my code.

```
def change_password(username, new_password):
    """Changes user password"""
    user_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sys.path[0] + "\\" + "passfile.csv"))
    user_data.set_index('usernames',inplace=True)


    print('TEST1', file=sys.stderr)
    user_data.loc[username]['passwords'] = 4
    print(user_data)
    print('TEST2', file=sys.stderr)
            
    user_data.reset_index()
    user_data.to_csv(os.path.join(sys.path[0] + "\\" + "passfile.csv"))
    flash('Changed Password!')
```

```
@app.route('/password_update.html', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def password_update():

    """Allows user to update their password"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_username = request.form['username'].lower()
        login_password = request.form['password']
        new_password = request.form['password_update']

        if login_username:

            if verify_user(login_username, login_password):

                if good_password(new_password):

                    change_password(login_username,new_password)
                else:
                    flash('Password does not meet standards. Try new one.')
            else:
                flash('Invalid username or password')
        else:
            flash('Please enter username and password.')
```

***Update 2***

It was in fact my parameters in loc.

This

```
 user_data.loc[username]['passwords'] = 4
```

should be this

```
 user.data.loc[username, 'passwords'] = 4
```

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for `.loc`

```
df.loc[username, 'passwords'] = 4
```

And I also notice your `set_index()` hasn't been implemented correctly.

You should either add `inplace=True` or set the value to df again

```
user_data.set_index('usernames', inplace=True)
```

OR

```
user_data = user_data.set_index('usernames')
```

Otherwise the set_index() won't change the df itself

Comment: Nothing happened with the 
```
user_data.loc[username, 'passwords'] = 4
```
There was no change in my csv file. I did get the same warning in console though. Which is below.
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  user_data.loc[username]['passwords'] = 4

Thank you for the inplace tip though!

Comment: do a `print("TEST")` in that condition to see whether that part of the code is being executed. I think python isn't reaching the `.loc` command

Comment: or debug by seeing whether the `username` you're sending is actually one of the values in the index. 
You can post your data here and what value of username/password you're using so we can see what the issue is

Comment: I created a TEST1 and TEST2 around  `.loc` command and both were printed out in console. Without anything being changed in the csv file. When I was testing before with just print(user_data), the value wasnt changed in that either.

Comment: `
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  user_data.loc[username]['passwords'] = 4
TEST2
`

Comment: Username is in the index. check_username(username) returns false if username is already in the index.

Comment: Im an idiot, sorry I didnt change my .loc[username, 'passwords]. I did not notice that in yours. Thank you for the help! I dont know why I did not notice that sooner! I think i need a break. It is working now!